# What is the relationship between 3 phase motor driving signal and its position encoder?

Tags: three-phase, induction-motor, motordriver

I have this project to add a magnetic encoder on the motor shaft that will allow speed control by utilizing a TB67B000AHG chip as a driver. I want to install 3 magnetic Hall sensors HW101 stationary 120 degree around the shaft.

Datasheets available below.

I am also fixing a cylindrical magnet with radial magnetic poles N-S. Preliminary testing shows that there is plenty of magnetic strength to get a decent signal voltage out of the HW101 sensors. The TB67 chip provides 3 inputs for the Hall sensors as well as 3 outputs U V W for feeding power to the three phase motor.

The tricky part that I need to figure out: The motor can be wired for low and high speed by switching from star to delta configuration. It became obvious after some serious investigation that the relationship between the input frequency and the RPM is definitely not 1:1, which implies that the Hall sensors will send a shaft position to the TB67 which is not directly related to the 3 power signal outputs U V W frequency.

In the TB67 datasheet starting from page 18 up to 25 it shows different waveform diagrams showing a direct relationship 1:1 (frequency wise) between the Hall sensor inputs and the power waveform sent to the motor. Nowhere in the datasheet is it explained how the TB67 could handle a situation where the motor could necessitate 2 cycles for each rotation (or any other numbers, for that matter.) The ID plate on the motor specifies an RPM of 2660 or 1380 for a 50Hz power signal input. So, the RPM versus frequency relationship is 0.89:1 and 0.46:1 ( when free running.) It is not 1:1 and 0.5:1 because of the squirrel cage motor slip.

The questions:

1. Where in the TB67B000 datasheet can I read the information to indicate how the driver chip will behave and how to handle this particular situation?
2. Is there a way to configure the TB67B000 such that it will run "Open Loop" with no Hall sensor? The datasheet doesn't seem to mention such configuration.

[This project is also related to this other question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/617166/how-is-the-winding-cross-induction-of-a-3-phases-motor-magnetically-interact-fro/617200?noredirect=1#comment1628798_617200)

[Link to GoogleDrive datasheets for HW101 and TB67000](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ifWFLAfwjzLt_bOJcnWZyoU4TwAO-IKi?usp=sharing)

Comment: _"It is not 1:1 and 0.5:1 because of the Squirrel Cage Motor slip"_ - and that makes hall sensor commutation control useless. You need to run the controller 'open loop' without position feedback.

Comment: I suspected that. So my question should have been:  How can I configure the TB67 for "Open Loop" operation ? I cannot see any such information to that effect in the TB67 datasheet, any idea ?

Comment: After a quick glance at the datasheet, I am thinking that the TB6700 is not designed to drive induction motors. If you want to trick it into generating the sinusoidal waveform for an induction motor, you can generate a reference speed signal and drive the sensor inputs with your reference signal instead of actual hall sensor signals. The actual slip of the motor will be a function of output torque. More torque means more slip.

Comment: I was going to make the same suggestion that @mkeith has already, and add that if you're going through the trouble of spoofing three phase sine waves, you might as well just control the output yourself using an intelligent power module:
https://www.digikey.ca/short/fnb83tnf